# Teams ID or AAD Object ID: Which is a better identifier to use?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot service which integrates with Teams. All the interactions will happen via Teams. Their access to Teams serves as their authentication into our system.

The question is whether I should use the Teams ID or the Azure Active Directory (AAD) Object ID as the unique identifier for that user. What are the pros/cons of each? What are other considerations I should factor in. Is either of them more likely to change? What am I not considering that I should be considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Active Directory (AAD) Object ID is the best way to uniquely identify the user.

Also Multiple Teams can contains same users, so if you need a requirement where you want to uniquely identity the user's in different Teams, you can use a custom combination of (Team Id + AAD Object Id).

Comment: To clarify, when you say "Multiple Teams", you mean the same user could be added to Teams accounts at different organizations? Or, just different Teams at the same organization? That might be an important distinction for our needs.

Comment: Also, why not use just Team Id? Why do you suggest a combination? What additional value does that provide over just the Team Id?

Comment: @YKStacker -  "Multiple Teams" means teams/groups which we create in a particular Tenant/Organization.
I am not suggesting you to use a combination and it's totally depend on our requirements and implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, either one is fine as long as it uniquely identifies the user, and both are "Ids" so they do that. However, the one is purely from a bot perspective, and so it's not even Teams-wide. For instance, if you add a tab to your app later, you'll only get the user's AAD Id, and that's presuming you don't -ever- want to do anything more broadly. So I'd strongly suggest, given the option, to rather use the AAD Id.